# google app engine alternative to spring security

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

We have to avoid using Spring on our application Google app engine Java EE.

I'm wondering if you know a framework google to handle authentication Security - authorization with roles and rights like spring here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/authz-arch.html  ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Here is an example in Google App Engine: https://gaeshiro.appspot.com/